# Update Table if source modified

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, datasource

I know the title is not self-explaining but I don't know how to express this.
There is a site which keeps updating a small database opensource in many different formats, and I have a table in my DB that I want to be "linked" to that DB, so that if the DB gets updated the table gets cleared and repopulated with new data.
I am working with Rails and MySql as Database I don't know if this is possible, but any help would be appreciated, even a hint on what to google...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you have access to codebase of both apps.*

Suppose you have app `A` & `B`. You can create a rake task in `A` which will be triggered periodically via cronjob. The rake task will populate database of `B` through exposed api of `B` (accessible through secret api-key).

Hope you got the idea.